# Implementing Drag And Drop on multiple buttons

Tags: c#, oop, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to get multiple buttons to be fully independently draggable on WP 7/8, but I'm having some trouble.

My main problem is that I have this layout set up...

[enter link description here](http://imgur.com/gfm1a0T)

And I'd like to be able to independetly drag the buttons away if I want. Now the dragging works fine as far as one button, but as soon as I release it and try to drag another one, it just "snaps" beside the first button I pressed, and this goes on and on until all the buttons are moving at the same time.

So basically when this "snapping" occurs, multiple buttons start to move together as if they were only one button.

Here's my XAML code:

```
<Grid Name="buttons_container" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <toolkit:WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="wrapPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="600">
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="1" Height="70" Name="button2" Width="150">

        </Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="2" Height="70" Name="button3" Width="150" ></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="3" Height="70" Name="button4" Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="4" Height="70" Name="button5"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="5" Height="70" Name="button6"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="6" Height="70" Name="button7"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="7" Height="70" Name="button8"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="8" Height="70" Name="button9"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="9" Height="70" Name="button10"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="10" Height="70" Name="button11" Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="11" Height="70" Name="button12"  Width="150"></Button>
        <Button ManipulationDelta="Drag_ManipulationDelta" Content="12" Height="70" Name="button13" Width="150"></Button>
    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's my C# code:

```
private TranslateTransform dragTranslation; - global

dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform(); - in constructor of the class

        void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Button draggedButton = (Button)sender;

            draggedButton.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
            dragTranslation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
            dragTranslation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem caused by this lines :

```
dragTranslation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
dragTranslation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
```

that incrementing `X` and `Y` properties of `dragTranslation` everytime. Try to reset value of `X` and `Y` to it's initial value before increment. Or you can simply assign new value (instead of add current value with new value) if the initial values are zero.

```
dragTranslation.X = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
dragTranslation.Y = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However if I make the changes you mentioned, the buttons just get "stuck" to their initial position. They look like they are "trying" to get away, but a big magnetic force is keeping them back. It's really hard to explain.

Comment: maybe try with suggestion from the other answer too, try to create new TraslateTransform in the event handler (`dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();`) instead of reusing the same object.

Comment: Same thing happens if I do this. It looks like to me, that since the event handler is getting called every time a pixel is moved ("dragged") and is resetting the initial position of the button I'm trying to drag. If I'm really careful and fast, I can "flick" away the button, but at the very moment when I try to drag again, it continues this.

Answer (score 1):

In the code all the `sender` objects (`draggedButton`) are having `RenderTransform` set to the same object - `dragTranslation`.

When the values for `X` and `Y` for `dragTranslation` is changed it is affecting all the objects that are having reference to the common object - `dragTranslation`.

If so, try having an instance per object. You can think of optimization if this works.

Or the problem could be because of incrementing values as suggested by **@har07**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Please check comment #3 under @har07's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was pretty simple and logical. 
As **@Sandeep G B** had stated, the *snapping* occured because all the buttons were using the same TranslateTransform object.

I just needed to create an event handler when the drag is started, and create a new TranslateTransform object there.

```
private void Drag_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
            draggedButton = (Button)sender;
        }

        private void Drag_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            draggedButton.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
            dragTranslation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
            dragTranslation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        }
```